# How to iterate through Nested XML after parsing using groovy with slurper or parser

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy, xmlslurper

I'm Facing an issue with iteration of below xml because it neglects some part.
Can anyone guide me through this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fruits type="array">
    <fruit>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <alias>App</alias>
        <colors>
            <color>Red</color>
            <color>Green</color>
        </colors>
        <available-in type="array">
            <country>
                <name>Ind</id>
            </country>
            <country>
                <name>Ind</id>
            </country>
        </available-in>
    </fruit>
</fruits>
```

please find the Groovy code I used below

```
def map = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response).children().collectEntries{n->[(n.name()):{->n.children()?.collectEntries(owner)?:n.text()}()]};
```

Comment: The country names are not well-formed with valid closing tags: `<name>Ind</id>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groovy's [GPath capability called depthFirst()](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_flexible_navigation_with_children_depthfirst_and_breadthfirst) to iterate over all the children like so:

```
def map = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response).depthFirst().collectEntries{[(it.name()): it.text()]}
```